# How to recognize Indian names via NER in OpenNLP?

Tags: java, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I am using OpenNLP models for Name-entity recognition, but the problem is that it will only recognize US and UK based names (foreign names), so I need to recognize Indian names.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

NER solutions tend to be domain-specific, using either hardcoded word lists as signals(features) and/or internal letter structure of the named entities.

UK/USA names are similar among themselves and also to other European names, as lots of popular USA names and surnames come from non-English European immigrants. Indian names are significantly different, and commonly used lists of names/surnames and training data corpora generally do not include much or any Indian-specific data.

To solve your problem, you would need to train a specialized NER model based on data suitable for your particular domain.

Comment: is there any other option for recognized Indian names entity ? likes other opensource tools etc.. @peteris